# Squid and Click-Through Authentication

Tags: linux, authentication, squid

I need a simple solution here... I'm pretty sure this is possible, I just don't know how to set it up.

I need squid to redirect all users to a simple user acceptance agreement before allowing them out to the internet. No username and password, they either accept the agreement and get allowed access, or the don't and get a permission denied page.

I don't want to have anything complicated, lets keep it simple if we can.

I have reviewed this: http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Portal/Splash#Portal_Splash_Pages

However its not very clear to me...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

From auth_param section in squid.conf file:

> Specify the command for the external authenticator. Such a program
>   reads a line containing "username password" and replies "OK" or "ERR"
>   in an endless loop. "ERR" responses may optionally be followed by a
>   error description available as %m in the returned error page.
>
> By default, the basic authentication scheme is not used unless a
>   program is specified.

There are lots of examples around. This [link](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/authentication_with_squid) has an example of a custom squid helper in PHP. It can easily be modified to have a checkbox for agreement iso a username/password authentication.